# Java Collections.sort return null when sorting list of strings

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I am trying to sort a list of strings (that will contain alphanumeric characters as well as punctuation) via `Collections.sort`:

```
public class SorterDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> toSort = new ArrayList<String>();

        toSort.add("fizzbuzz");
        System.out.println("toSort size is " + toSort.size());

        List<String> sorted = Collections.sort(toSort);
        if(sorted == null) {
            System.out.println("I am null and sad.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I am not null.");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
toSort size is 1
I am null and sad.
```

Why null?

Comment: Are you sure that code compiles? `Collections.sort()` has return type `void`...

Comment: `Collections.sort()` has `void` as its return type. It modifies the `List` it is passed.

Comment: Yes @Thomas - my actual code is in Groovy but I converted it to Java to expedite the answering of the question. It seems Groovy's dynamic nature covers up what Java would immediately expose as a compiler error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) returns a `void`, so your new collection `sorted` is never initialized.

```
List<String> sorted = Collections.sort(toSort);
```

is like

```
List<String> sorted = null;
Collections.sort(toSort);    
//                 ^------------> toSort is being sorted!
```

To use correctly the  `Collections.sort()` method you must know **you are sorting the same object you put in the method**:

```
Collections.sort(collectionToBeSorted);
```

In your case:

```
public class SorterDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> toSort = new ArrayList<String>();

        toSort.add("fizzbuzz");
        System.out.println("toSort size is " + toSort.size());

        Collections.sort(toSort);
        if(toSort == null) {
            System.out.println("I am null and sad.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I am not null.");
        }
    }
}
```